# Autocomplete don't return a searched value, but it return all value (in PHP, jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, autocomplete

I have `index.php` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/theme/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("name").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: 'autocomplete.php',
            select: function(event,ui){
                $("#name").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
</form>
```

And this is a part of `autocomplete.php`

```
$q = $_GET['name'];
...
$sql = "SELECT name_name FROM tbl_data WHERE name_name LIKE '%$q%'"
...
```

And it return a value as a `json` format.

But, when I type two letter in `inputbox`, it shows me all name from `tbl_data`, not only the data `LIKE '%$q'`.

How to solve this?

Any response, Thanks..

Comment: Maybe all names suit your query?

Comment: I fix it! I just replace LIKE '%$q%' to LIKE '%$_REQUEST['term']%.. but why 'term'? anyone can explain? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must be more specific about your jQuery selector:

```
$('#name').autocomplete({...});
```

But the part that I think you do wrong is the part in your PHP code that you retrieve that variable from `_GET` array, the name of the variable that jQuery sends to server is `q` not `name` so your code should be like:

```
$q = _GET['q'];
```

Comment: I agree with you, something must be wrong in php side. but I don't, about $_GET['q'] because, $q = $_GET['this-is-a-name-of-input-box'], I named mine as 'name' so I use $_GET['name']

Answer (score 1):

This problem fixed!
I just replace the query from "SELECT name_name FROM tbl_data WHERE name_name LIKE '%$q%'" to be "SELECT name_name FROM tbl_data WHERE name_name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'".. This works! Even I don't really sure why using 'term'. Perhaps, it is a keyword that return by jQuery. Any explanation of this will be accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

A **request** object, with a single **term** property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".

```
$q = $_GET["term"];
```